# How to hide HTML table until there is data in the search box and display a "No Results Found" if no matches are found?

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I tried making the table hidden when the HTML opens but for some reason I can't get it to work with `table.style.display = "none";` so I omitted it in the code below.

I wanted the table to be hidden when the HTML is first opened. Then if a value entered in the input box, it should only search the second column of the table and when it matches an entry, it will unhide the table and display only the rows that match the input, with the rest of the rows remaining hidden.

If there are no results, then the table should remain hidden and return a "No Results Found" instead when there is no exact match in the column being searched.

The script is just a mix of whatever codes I found online and pasted it in the HTML since I don't know how to work with JavaScript yet. So if there are any redundancies, I'd like to get it fixed too.

Full HTML code here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>database search test</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  font-family: "Lucida Console";
    color: white;
    text-shadow:
    -1px -1px 0 #000,
    1px -1px 0 #000,
    -1px 1px 0 #000,
    1px 1px 0 #000;
}
h3 {
  font-family: "Lucida Console";
  color: #99ff33;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 10px #99ff33;
}
html{
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
th {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid white;
}
#myInput {
  height: 50px;
  width: 310px;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 50px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
#myTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-size: 18px;
}
#myTable th, #myTable td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 12px;
}
#myTable tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
#myTable tr.header, #myTable tr:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h3> Database Search:
<br>
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Input your column 2 data" title="Type in Pixiv UserID">
<br>
<br>
<h2> Database Search Results: </h2>
</center>
<table id="myTable">
    <tr>
    <th>Column 1</th>
    <th>Column 2</th>
    <th>Column 3</th>
    <th>Column 4</th>
    <th>Column 5</th>
    <th>Column 6</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>DB-000001</td>
  <td>21029246</td>
  <td>247638</td>
  <td>SLI-20-0002</td>
  <td>08-03-2020, 0405 UTC</td>
  <td>358735864</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>DB-000002</td>
  <td>4338012</td>
  <td>4634638</td>
  <td>SLI-20-0002</td>
  <td>08-03-2020, 0405 UTC</td>
  <td>13624176537</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>DB-000003</td>
  <td>4338012</td>
  <td>456378</td>
  <td>SLI-20-0002</td>
  <td>08-03-2020, 0405 UTC</td>
  <td>247582671</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>DB-000004</td>
  <td>4338012</td>
  <td>77378678</td>
  <td>SLI-20-0002</td>
  <td>08-03-2020, 0405 UTC</td>
    <td>175274246</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>DB-000005</td>
  <td>432627</td>
  <td>984327/td>
  <td>SLI-20-0002</td>
  <td>08-03-2020, 0405 UTC</td>
  <td>474638286</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>DB-000006</td>
  <td>789346</td>
  <td>12643458</td>
  <td>SLI-20-0002</td>
  <td>08-03-2020, 0405 UTC</td>
  <td>35723747</td>
</tr>
<table>
<script>
    function myFunction() {
      var input, filter, table, tr, td, cell, i, j;
      input = document.getElementById("myInput");
      filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
      table = document.getElementById("myTable");
      tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
      for (i = 1; i < tr.length; i++) {
        // Hide the row initially.
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
        for (var j = 0; j < td.length; j++) {
          cell = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
          if (cell) {
            if (cell.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
              tr[i].style.display = "";
              break;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Get rid of your `j` loop entirely, then should be more like `let row = tr[i]; row.style = row.getElementsByTagName('td')[1].textContent().toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1 ? 'block' : 'none';`. I would like to say that JavaScript is doing more processing than necessary, using your `myFunction` since it gets the Elements every time your Event occurs. Unless the Elements are subject to dynamic activity, you should get them once.

Comment: So... how should I rewrite the script @StackSlave? I removed the `j` loop and was left with this:

`<script>
 function myFunction() {
   var input, filter, table, tr, td, cell, i, j;
   input = document.getElementById("myInput");
   filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
   table = document.getElementById("myTable");
   tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  let row = tr[i];
  row.style = row.getElementsByTagName('td')[1].textContent().toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1 ? 'block' : 'none';

}
</script>`